# Getting Invalid Packet Length when running SonarQube Job (from Bamboo)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sonarqube

We are using SonarQube 4.5.6 and invoking jobs from Bamboo Build plans.

Last night one of the Bamboo builds failed showing this error (date `06-Jan-2016 00:07:04`):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project plantmaterial-overall: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@5ae75570[key=src/main/java/com/bayer/plantmaterial/service/mission/MissionInitiatedServiceImpl.java,deprecatedKey=com.bayer.plantmaterial.service.mission.MissionInitiatedServiceImpl,path=src/main/java/com/bayer/plantmaterial/service/mission/MissionInitiatedServiceImpl.java,dir=com/bayer/plantmaterial/service/mission,filename=MissionInitiatedServiceImpl.java,language=Java]':
[ERROR] ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Invalid Packet Lenght
[ERROR] ### The error may exist in org.sonar.core.source.db.SnapshotSourceMapper
[ERROR] ### The error may involve org.sonar.core.source.db.SnapshotSourceMapper.selectSnapshotSourceByComponentKey-Inline
[ERROR] ### The error occurred while setting parameters
[ERROR] ### SQL: SELECT data     FROM snapshot_sources source     INNER JOIN snapshots s ON s.id=source.snapshot_id and s.islast=1     INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id=s.project_id and p.enabled=1     WHERE p.kee = ?
[ERROR] ### Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Invalid Packet Lenght
```

Looks like an Oracle JDBC error
This was a nightly build, I ran it manually and then it succeeded.  Is this a glitch or what could be the cause?

Comment: [This test program](https://blogs.oracle.com/LuzMestre/entry/troubleshooting_java_sql_sqlrecoverableexception_io) might be useful; but you might also have left a connection in an odd state ([as here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/674137/266304)), or have one of the other issues searching for that error reveals. Not enough info to attempt to narrow it down.

Comment: I'm using Bamboo with a Sonar Task here. No custom code. I am wondering if this is a glitch or a known bug in Sonar